# Issue with modulo and array index in php

Tags: php, modulo

I'm trying to create an html table from database records. I want the table to be 4 cells wide, so I figured if the array index of the row I'm looping through is a multiple of 4, then add a tr tag at the beginning. However, it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Can anyone help me out? (This is CodeIgniter, so the echo anchor, etc. just creates an a href tag.)

```
<table width="80%" border="1">
<tr> <!-- create initial tr tag, since we haven't started the loop yet -->
<?php foreach($projects as $index=>$project) : ?>
    <?php echo ((($index + 1) % 4 == 0) ? '<tr>' : ''); ?>
    <td>
    <?php echo anchor('project/view/'.$project->id, $project->project_name, 'title='.$project->project_name); ?>
    </td>
    <?php echo ((($index + 1) % 4 == 0) ? '</tr>' : ''); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
 </table>
```

The $index + 1 is because dividing by 0 (where the array index starts) causes an error. I echoed out the values of $index+1 on each row, and if I have 5 rows in my table I get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. But the line that should create the tr tag if $index+1 does not divide evenly by 4 isn't evaluating; I'm getting a single row table that just keeps getting wider.

Here's what I'd expect to see as rendered code:

```
<table width="80%" border="1">
  <tr> 
    <td><a href="http://localhost/ignite/index.php/project/view/1" title=Basil's Beatnik Turtle>Basil's Beatnik Turtle</a></td> 
    <td><a href="http://localhost/ignite/index.php/project/view/2" title=Mr. Werewolf Genes>Mr. Werewolf Genes</a></td> 
    <td><a href="http://localhost/ignite/index.php/project/view/3" title=Romeo+Juliet>Romeo+Juliet</a></td> 
    <td><a href="http://localhost/ignite/index.php/project/view/4" title=Basic Hat>Basic Hat</a></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- I'm not trying to auto-generate empty cells to fill in a final row that contains fewer than 4 at this point, although it would be nice -->
    <td><a href="http://localhost/ignite/index.php/project/view/5" title=Flutterby Hat>Flutterby Hat</a></td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's what I'm actually getting:

```
<table width="80%" border="1">
  <tr> 
    <td><a href="http://localhost/ignite/index.php/project/view/1" title=Basil's Beatnik Turtle>Basil's Beatnik Turtle</a></td> 
    <td><a href="http://localhost/ignite/index.php/project/view/2" title=Mr. Werewolf Genes>Mr. Werewolf Genes</a></td> 
    <td><a href="http://localhost/ignite/index.php/project/view/3" title=Romeo+Juliet>Romeo+Juliet</a></td> 
  <!-- note the lack of closing </tr> tag on previous chunk - plus it's only 3 cells, not 4 -->

  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://localhost/ignite/index.php/project/view/4" title=Basic Hat>Basic Hat</a></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- this previous chunk has both <tr> and </tr>, but only contains one <td> -->

    <td><a href="http://localhost/ignite/index.php/project/view/5" title=Flutterby Hat>Flutterby Hat</a></td> 
  <!-- the previous chunk is missing both <tr> and </tr> tags, and is only a single cell -->
</table>
```

Basil's Beatnik Turtle 
Mr. Werewolf Genes 
Romeo+Juliet 
 tag on previous chunk - plus it's only 3 cells, not 4 -->


Basic Hat

 and , but only contains one  -->

Flutterby Hat 
 and  tags, and is only a single cell -->

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What does `print_r(projects)` o/p ? Are you sure the `$index` is a number?

Comment: are you able to use pure php in CodeIgniter?  All those long tags and odd markup are throwing me off.

EDIT: nevermind, it looks like anchor() is just a custom function, that's the only difference.  You might consider turning on short_tags so you can write <? instead of <?php

Comment: @thrustmaster - yes, $index is a number, and $projects is returning everything I expect. I've echoed $index at the end of each anchor tag that's created from $project->name, etc.

Comment: @rockerest - yes, you can use pure PHP in CodeIgniter. And anchor is not a custom function, it's part of the URL helper - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the data that's being returned from the SQL query looks like, it seems like $index is not what you are expecting it to be.

I humbly suggest this alternative:

```
<?
$count = 1;
foreach($projects as $index=>$project)
{
    if($count % 4 == 0)
    {
         print "</tr><tr>";
    }
    print "<td>" . anchor('project/view/'.$project->id, $project->project_name, 'title='.$project->project_name) . "</td>";
    $count++;
}
?>
```

Comment: $index is actually exactly what I'm expecting it to be - I've echoed it out. However, your version, in spite of the extra variable, is much cleaner than mine, so I'll give it a try.

Comment: Remember that, per @Phoenix 's suggestion, you will need to handle the end case where you will not write a final `</tr>`.  My first thought would be to check `$count` outside the loop for whether it's **1 MORE** than divisible by four (since we add 1 at the end of the loop), and if it's not, then loop through something that prints some `<td>` s and a final `</tr>` until it reaches the proper divisible status.  However, there is probably a more graceful solution to that problem.

Comment: This also adds an empty starting tr

Comment: @Hanoncs While I find this code pretty bad all around (shame on me 4.5 years ago!) I don't believe that this does add a leading empty `tr`. `$count` starts at `1`, meaning the check to print `</tr><tr>` (which a browser would helpfully match to avoid dangling tags) doesn't happen until 3 loops later (0 => `1%4 == 1`, 1=> `2%4 == 2`, 2=> `3%4 == 3`, 3 => `4%4 == 0`)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest switching to using a counter variable, also, you'll need to rethink the last part of it, because unless it ends on a multiple of 4, it's not gonna give you the final /tr either.

Here's how I'd do it, and I'd also get rid of those awful ternary operators:

```
<table width="80%" border="1">
<?php
$i = 1;
foreach($projects as $index=>$project)
{
    if($i == 1)
    {
          echo '<tr>';
    }

    echo '<td>' . anchor('project/view/'.$project->id, $project->project_name, 'title='.$project->project_name) . '</td>';

    if($i == 4)
    {
          echo '</tr>';
          $i = 0;
    }

    $i++;
} 

if($i != 1) //Catch it if it doesn't end evenly, since $i will == 1 if it ended on a multiple of 4
{
     while($i <= 4) //Create empty cells to even table out, table will quite possibly look funky otherwise 
     {
         echo '<td></td>';
         $i++;
     }
     echo '</tr>'; //End table row
}
?>
 </table>
```

If you want it to look nice, append `PHP_EOL` or `"\n"` to the end of each echo statement.  If you want it to look really nice, you could prepend `"\t"` to certain echo statements to give it the look of a manually indented and hand coded html.

Comment: I happen to find ternary operators easier to read than the multi-line if statements.

Comment: You and very few other people.  But at least this gives you the logic required to properly format the rows and catch uneven endings.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred solution for things like this is breaking it out into a helper function ([codeigniter details](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html)). It keeps the markup cleaner and makes sure that after you've solved it once you don't have to rethink it.

Here's a crack and what you're after. It will return a multidimensional array of rows that you can iterate over.

```
function rowify($array, $perRow) {
    $currentRow = 0;
    $counter = 0;
    $new = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $element) {
        if ($counter % 4 == 0) {
            ++$currentRow;
            $new[$currentRow] = array();
        }
        $new[$currentRow][$key] = $element;
        ++$counter;
    }
    return $new;
}
```

Using this, your markup will look like:

```
<table width="80%" border="1">
<?php foreach(rowify($projects,4) as $row) : ?>
  <tr>
    <?php foreach ($row as $index=>$project):?>
      <td>
        <?php echo anchor('project/view/'.$project->id, $project->project_name, 'title='.$project->project_name); ?>
      </td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
 </table>
```

which I think is quite elegant - no if statements, no echo ''; stuff, just iteration.

Comment: I'd already accepted a previous answer, but this is great. I'm just getting my feet wet with CodeIgniter, and haven't gotten as far as creating my own helper functions yet. I'm keeping this one.

Comment: Hmm, I think your code is solid but I disagree with your reasoning.  The code in the page doesn't make any sense unless you know what "rowify" does, and I think it drastically lessens the maintainability of the code.  Not to mention, now there's a function that has to be called when the page renders, which will slow the processing down a little bit.  There are tradeoffs, to be sure, but I'd personally rather see the code all in one spot (in this case) so it's obvious what is happening, it's easy to understand, and it's maintainable.  These are all top priorities in my book.

Comment: @rockerest - the idea of a helper function is that it's something that can be reused. It makes more sense to me to keep it in its own file, so if I ever need to change what it does, I only need to change it in one place. In MY book, that's maintainable, not having to search multiple files to find all the places I might have used the code. Also, "rowify" is just an arbitrary name Allan used. It could have been called "outputArrayAsTableRows" or something equally descriptive.

Comment: I agree and understand the concept of a helper function, but you're coming at it from the wrong angle.  If you have to write  a helper function that parses your data every time you want to render it, that's not useful.  The functionality in this helper function needs to be in the object that's pulling the data.  That way, you just print the data using the `foreach` that Allen wrote and it all works.  If you're having to include a helper file on every page that needs to render data, that's not very helpful.

Comment: You definitely dont't want to have to throw "include 'myHelper.php' at the top all the time - CI will let you autoload helpers fortunately. You also don't want helpers to be so specific that they are useful only in one or two spots or even for only one kind of object - they should be general. I think it works here (though it might need a better name) - it handles all cases where you need to split up an array into chunks and then iterate over those chunks...chunkify()? I don't think this functionality belongs in the object though - this is definitely the kind of thing that belongs in the view.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you're adding a tr at the beginning of every fourth cell, and a end tr at the end of every fourth cell. The end tr needs to be added after the fourth cell, and the tr should be added before the **fifth** one.

Comment: Ugh. I'm new at this formatting thing. I can't figure out how to display tr and end tr html elements.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it - you're using the exact same logic check to place the opening `<tr>` as the closing `</tr>`.  This means that every 4th element will be surrounded by an opening row tag and a closing row tag.

Comment: From my reading of the question, I actually *don't* think she was intending to put every 4th element on its own row.

Comment: Nope - every 4th element is supposed to START a new row.

Answer (score 0):

if it helps - here is some old code I dug out that does it - not codeigniter but should guide you - have taken my db stuff out to clean it up:

```
define('NUMCOLS', 4);
$count = 0;
$counter = 1;
//create table
echo '<table width = \"100%\" border = 1 cellpadding = 0>';
//create a table row for each book   
foreach ($book_array as $row)
{
  // get your data
  if($count % NUMCOLS == 0) //new row
    echo '<tr>';
    echo'<td>';
    // display data
    echo '</td>';
    $count++;
   $counter++;
  if($count % NUMCOLS ==0)
    echo '</tr>'; //end row
}
echo '</table>';
}
}
```